# Angular 8 template with input with template variable reference

Tags: angular, templates, variables, input, reference

I have an Angular 8 application with a lot of custom inputs and custom validation messages under each input. I want to optimize all components and their input, select, checkbox implementations to use template instead of lot of duplicated code:

```html
<div class="component-atom sp-form-item">
                <label class="sp-form-label" for="user-first-name">First Name</label>
                <div class="sp-form-item error-input">
                  <div class="sp-form-group">
                    <input id="user-first-name" [(ngModel)]="userData.firstName" name="userFirstName" type="text"
                      class="sp-text-input details-input form-control" placeholder="First Name" required
                      #userFirstName="ngModel">
                    <button class="clear-icon" type="button"><i class="sp-icon-close"></i></button>
                  </div>
                  <div *ngIf="isInvalid(userFirstName)" class="sp-form-requirement">
                    <i class="sp-icon-error input-error-icon"></i><span class="error-message">Required</span>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
```

And so far I have this template which works ok:

```html
<div class="component-atom sp-form-item">
  <label class="sp-form-label" [for]="inputID">User ID</label>
  <div class="sp-form-group">
    <input [id]="inputID" [readonly]="readonly" [(ngModel)]="modelObject" [name]="modelName" [type]="inputType"
      class="sp-text-input details-input form-control" [placeholder]="placeholder" [required]="required" >
    <button class="clear-icon" type="button"><i class="sp-icon-close"></i></button>
  </div>
</div>
```

But now I have issue with this part #userFirstName="ngModel" also known as Template variable references https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel#template-variable-references

This is needed for `*ngIf="isInvalid(userFirstName)` where :

```js
isInvalid(control: NgModel) {
    return control.invalid && control.touched;
}
```

I'm also not sure if this is possible in angular, but I want to add for example #{{dynamicName}}="ngModel". I'm open for alternatives. All dynamic values will be unique but I could not find a correct syntax to implement #userFirstName="ngModel" in template where userFirstName is unique.

Comment: Can't you use static template reference to check validity?

Comment: Yes but this way I don't have access to control.touched validation of dom element. I can check only if value is empty but this way all Required messages will appear immediately when user open the page. But yes its one alternative.

Comment: Can you create stackbllitz?

Comment: Here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uxfnfk :) Its an simpler version - check app.component.html comments

Comment: Even you have same template varaible on the template, it's does not  matter bcoz It will have different component instance. In your example it's working fine

Comment: Actually you are completely right. I tried this in the original application and it works ok. I don't know how I get Required message on  both inputs when touch only one, but now is ok. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: In this scenario @Output property with EventEmiter also should be provided in order to update correctly the model in the parent :)